# sonar-scanner StackOverflowException -

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I am attempting to run `sonar-scanner` on a Maven project with about 80,000 classes.

(I know: the correct approach is to use `mvn sonar:sonar`, but I ended up with maybe one bug and 0 for all other metrics, perhaps due to its being a problematic legacy system with residual ant build files in it.)

Leaving aside for the moment the question of whether or how to refactor/redo this project, I'd like to understand whether I can use Sonar on it as-is.

Here is the error I get with `sonar-scanner` after it processes 11,000 classes:

```
A stack overflow occurred while analyzing file: ....
....
Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.returnsToStart(CFGLoop.java:100)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.collectBlocks(CFGLoop.java:87)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.returnsToStart(CFGLoop.java:100)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.collectBlocks(CFGLoop.java:87)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.returnsToStart(CFGLoop.java:100)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.collectBlocks(CFGLoop.java:87)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.returnsToStart(CFGLoop.java:100)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.collectBlocks(CFGLoop.java:87)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.returnsToStart(CFGLoop.java:100)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.collectBlocks(CFGLoop.java:87)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.returnsToStart(CFGLoop.java:100)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.collectBlocks(CFGLoop.java:87)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.returnsToStart(CFGLoop.java:100)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.collectBlocks(CFGLoop.java:87)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.returnsToStart(CFGLoop.java:100)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.collectBlocks(CFGLoop.java:87)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.returnsToStart(CFGLoop.java:100)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.collectBlocks(CFGLoop.java:87)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.returnsToStart(CFGLoop.java:100)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.collectBlocks(CFGLoop.java:87)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.returnsToStart(CFGLoop.java:100)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.collectBlocks(CFGLoop.java:87)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.returnsToStart(CFGLoop.java:100)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.collectBlocks(CFGLoop.java:87)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.returnsToStart(CFGLoop.java:100)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.collectBlocks(CFGLoop.java:87)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.returnsToStart(CFGLoop.java:100)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.collectBlocks(CFGLoop.java:87)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.returnsToStart(CFGLoop.java:100)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.collectBlocks(CFGLoop.java:87)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.returnsToStart(CFGLoop.java:100)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.collectBlocks(CFGLoop.java:87)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.returnsToStart(CFGLoop.java:100)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.collectBlocks(CFGLoop.java:87)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.returnsToStart(CFGLoop.java:100)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.collectBlocks(CFGLoop.java:87)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.returnsToStart(CFGLoop.java:100)
at org.sonar.java.cfg.CFGLoop.collectBlocks(CFGLoop.java:87)
etc. many many more times.
```

In the `sonar-project.properties` file, I have:

```
sonar.sources=.
sonar.binaries=./<path>,./<another path>, etc.
```

Comment: I discovered how to scan all the source files using Sonar in Eclipse: add -Dsonar.sources=.

Answer (score -1):

I am answering my own question.

Per my comment, I am following the better practice of using `mvn` to run the `sonar` goal.

The problem which I will need to research, and perhaps post in another question, is why the analysis runs incredibly slowly - about a minute *for each file*.